# Sort a JavaScript array based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Is it possible to sort and rearrange an array that looks like the following?

```
itemsArray = [
    ['Anne', 'a'],
    ['Bob', 'b'],
    ['Henry', 'b'],
    ['Andrew', 'd'],
    ['Jason', 'c'],
    ['Thomas', 'b']
]
```

to match the arrangement of this array:

```
sortingArr = [ 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'd' ]
```

Unfortunately, I don’t have any IDs to keep track on. I would need to priority the items-array to match the sortingArr as close as possible.

Here is the output I’m looking for:

```
itemsArray = [
    ['Bob', 'b'],
    ['Jason', 'c'],
    ['Henry', 'b'],
    ['Thomas', 'b']
    ['Anne', 'a'],
    ['Andrew', 'd'],
]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: If you don't want to do everything manually, take a look at the array function sin [PHP.js](http://phpjs.org/functions/).

Comment: Where multiple arrays have the same sorting value (i.e. 'b') how do you decide which item goes where in the sorted array? With 'Bob', 'Henry' and 'Thomas' which all have the value 'b' - how do you decide which goes first, third and fourth?

Comment: Related: [Sorting objects by property values](/q/2466356/4642212), [Sorting arrays numerically by object property value](/q/7889006/4642212).

Answer (score 630, accepted):

One-Line answer.

```js
itemsArray.sort(function(a, b){  
  return sortingArr.indexOf(a) - sortingArr.indexOf(b);
});
```

Or even shorter:

```js
itemsArray.sort((a, b) => sortingArr.indexOf(a) - sortingArr.indexOf(b));
```

Comment: This will mutate `itemsArray`. Depending on the performance requirement, it would be a lot safer to do `itemsArray.slice().sort(...)`.

Comment: Important to have the 'return' keyword!

Comment: sort method return an array. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: It does return the array, but it also does the sort in place and mutates the original.

Comment: Can some-one explain why / how this works. I have tried it with data that is similar to the OPs, an array of objects of which one member is a GUID, and a sorting array of those GUIDs. I was dubious before I tried it and discovered that .. as I expected this had no effect on the order.

Comment: @Morvael, this is due to this answer requiring `sortingArr` to contain all values in `itemsArray`. The fix is to push items to the back of the array if they don't exist in `sortingArr` : ```allProducts.sort((product1, product2) => {
      const index1 = manualSort.indexOf(product1.id);
      const index2 = manualSort.indexOf(product2.id);
      return (
        (index1 > -1 ? index1 : Infinity) - (index2 > -1 ? index2 : Infinity)
      );
    });```

Comment: How about if I have to sort string array "names" based on another character array alpha.

    alpha = ['h','g','k','r','o','e','a','j','c','n','b']
    names = ['jack','rob','josh','john','greg']

The expected result should be
 

    ['greg','rob','john','josh','jack']

Tried 

    names.sort(function(a, b){  
      return alpha.indexOf(a) - alpha.indexOf(b);
    });

few more above given answers 

It just returns same array ??

Comment: This code doesn't produce the expected result from the question. `sortingArr.indexOf()` will always give `-1` in this case because neither `a` or `b` arrays from the `.sort()` callback are in `sortingArray`. It should have been `sortingArray.indexOf(a[1])` and the same with `b[1]`. But that still won't produce the expected result as it will sort _all_ `b` items first. With that said, I still think this answer is useful and will work for most people's use-case, just not the use-case that OP had.

Comment: It sorts in `descending` order.

Comment: I asked Chat GPT and it returned exactly the "or even shorter" answer. How interesting.

Comment: this asnwer returns the wrong result. it sortds the array by the order of first found index and omit all other unused values/indices of following wanted order. for me it's eiter this answer wrong or the question.

Comment: This answer is wrong! `a` and `b` are arrays, so the `sortingArr.indexOf(a) - sortingArr.indexOf(b)` always returns 0.

Comment: A bogus answer with more than 600 votes after more than seven years? There is something serious wrong the Stack Overflow model if that is true.

Answer (score 95):

Something like:

```
items = [
    ['Anne', 'a'],
    ['Bob', 'b'],
    ['Henry', 'b'],
    ['Andrew', 'd'],
    ['Jason', 'c'],
    ['Thomas', 'b']
]

sorting = [ 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];
result = []

sorting.forEach(function(key) {
    var found = false;
    items = items.filter(function(item) {
        if(!found && item[1] == key) {
            result.push(item);
            found = true;
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    })
})

result.forEach(function(item) {
    document.writeln(item[0]) /// Bob Jason Henry Thomas Andrew
})
```

Here's shorter code, but it destroys the `sorting` array:

```
result = items.map(function(item) {
    var n = sorting.indexOf(item[1]);
    sorting[n] = '';
    return [n, item]
}).sort().map(function(j) { return j[1] })
```

Comment: Quadratic complexity! Try it with a big amount of data…

Comment: @thg435: complexity has little to do with "optimization", unless the volume of data is guaranteed to be small (which may be the case here).

Comment: @georg When it comes to the complexity of algorithms acting on data structures, the optimizing of algorithms with quadratic (or worse) complexities is never premature and is always necessary (unless you can guarantee the size of the data set is going to be small). The difference in performance is (quite literally) expressed in orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 51):

If you use the native array sort function, you can pass in a custom comparator to be used when sorting the array. The comparator should return a negative number if the first value is less than the second, zero if they're equal, and a positive number if the first value is greater.

So if I understand the example you're giving correctly, you could do something like:

```
function sortFunc(a, b) {
  var sortingArr = [ 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];
  return sortingArr.indexOf(a[1]) - sortingArr.indexOf(b[1]);
}

itemsArray.sort(sortFunc);
```

Comment: That won't work, the resulting order would be b,b,b,c,c,d as `indexOf` returns the first index.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like the output of itemsArray to match the sortingArray.

Comment: I prefer this answer if the "ids" in the `sortingArr` are unique - which, thankfully, they are in my case :)

Comment: You should declare the `sortingArray` outside of the function to avoir re-declaring it on each sorting iteration

Answer (score 32):

### Case 1: Original Question (No Libraries)

Plenty of other answers that work. :)

### Case 2: Original Question (Lodash.js or Underscore.js)

```
var groups = _.groupBy(itemArray, 1);
var result = _.map(sortArray, function (i) { return groups[i].shift(); });
```

### Case 3: Sort Array1 as if it were Array2

I'm guessing that most people came here looking for an equivalent to PHP's array_multisort (I did) so I thought I'd post that answer as well. There are a couple options:

1. There's an existing [JS implementation of array_multisort()](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_multisort/). Thanks to @Adnan for pointing it out in the comments. It is pretty large, though.

2. Write your own. ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/donmccurdy/gL9c3cny/))

```
function refSort (targetData, refData) {
  // Create an array of indices [0, 1, 2, ...N].
  var indices = Object.keys(refData);

  // Sort array of indices according to the reference data.
  indices.sort(function(indexA, indexB) {
    if (refData[indexA] < refData[indexB]) {
      return -1;
    } else if (refData[indexA] > refData[indexB]) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  // Map array of indices to corresponding values of the target array.
  return indices.map(function(index) {
    return targetData[index];
  });
}
```

3. [Lodash.js](https://lodash.com) or [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) (both popular, smaller libraries that focus on performance) offer helper functions that allow you to do this:

```
    var result = _.chain(sortArray)
      .pairs()
      .sortBy(1)
      .map(function (i) { return itemArray[i[0]]; })
      .value();
```

...Which will (1) group the sortArray into `[index, value]` pairs, (2) sort them by the value (you can also provide a callback here), (3) replace each of the pairs with the item from the itemArray at the index the pair originated from.

Comment: Excellent solution, alternatively you can use _.indexBy and remove the shift if your data structure is a little more complex

Answer (score 23):

You could also use some modified version of the code below in [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) style. This code is for arrays like:

```js
var arrayToBeSorted = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arrayWithReferenceOrder = [3,5,8,9];
```

The actual operation:

```js
arrayToBeSorted = arrayWithReferenceOrder.filter(v => arrayToBeSorted.includes(v));
```

The actual operation in [ES5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2009):

```js
arrayToBeSorted = arrayWithReferenceOrder.filter(function(v) {
    return arrayToBeSorted.includes(v);
});
```

Should result in `arrayToBeSorted = [3,5]`

It does not destroy the reference array.

Comment: What if I the arrayToBeSorted is an Array of Objects ie: {1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…},  5: {…}}? but the arrayWithReferenceOrder is just a normal array?

Comment: @sushruth how does this sort the array?

Comment: @Crystal, that's an object, not an array of objects. The elements/items in an object have no order, that is, their order is not set. An array of objects would look something like `[{name: "1"}, {name: "2"}, {name: "3"}, ...]`.

Answer (score 20):

Something like:

```
//array1: array of elements to be sorted
//array2: array with the indexes

array1 = array2.map((object, i) => array1[object]);
```

The [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) function may not be available in all versions of JavaScript.

Comment: This is the cleanest answer, imo, but you don't need to use both `object` and `i`. Given an array `arr` of elements to be sorted and an array of indices `ind`:
`ind.map(index => arr[index])`

Answer (score 19):

```js
function sortFunc(a, b) {
  var sortingArr = ["A", "B", "C"];
  return sortingArr.indexOf(a.type) - sortingArr.indexOf(b.type);
}

const itemsArray = [
  {
    type: "A",
  },
  {
    type: "C",
  },
  {
    type: "B",
  },
];
console.log(itemsArray);
itemsArray.sort(sortFunc);
console.log(itemsArray);
```

Answer (score 12):

ES6

```js
const arrayMap = itemsArray.reduce(
  (accumulator, currentValue) => ({
    ...accumulator,
    [currentValue[1]]: currentValue,
  }),
  {}
);
const result = sortingArr.map(key => arrayMap[key]);
```

[More examples](https://www.canrau.com/en/es6-sort-an-array-based-on-another-array) with different input arrays

Comment: The result is `[["Thomas","b"],["Jason","c"],["Thomas","b"],["Thomas","b"],["Anne","a"],["Andrew","d"]]` which is incorrect.

Answer (score 9):

In case you get here needing to do this with an array of objects, here is an adaptation of [Durgpal Singh's awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/sort-a-javascript-array-based-on-another-array/44063445#44063445):

```
const itemsArray = [
  { name: 'Anne', id: 'a' },
  { name: 'Bob', id: 'b' },
  { name: 'Henry', id: 'b' },
  { name: 'Andrew', id: 'd' },
  { name: 'Jason', id: 'c' },
  { name: 'Thomas', id: 'b' }
]

const sortingArr = [ 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'd' ]

Object.keys(itemsArray).sort((a, b) => {
  return sortingArr.indexOf(itemsArray[a].id) - sortingArr.indexOf(itemsArray[b].id);
})
```

Answer (score 8):

I would use an intermediary object (`itemsMap`), thus avoiding quadratic complexity:

```
function createItemsMap(itemsArray) { // {"a": ["Anne"], "b": ["Bob", "Henry"], …}
  var itemsMap = {};
  for (var i = 0, item; (item = itemsArray[i]); ++i) {
    (itemsMap[item[1]] || (itemsMap[item[1]] = [])).push(item[0]);
  }
  return itemsMap;
}

function sortByKeys(itemsArray, sortingArr) {
  var itemsMap = createItemsMap(itemsArray), result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < sortingArr.length; ++i) {
    var key = sortingArr[i];
    result.push([itemsMap[key].shift(), key]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/eUskE/

Comment: What is the complexity of the resulting implementation?

Comment: @PeterMortensen  O(n)

Answer (score 6):

```
var sortedArray = [];
for(var i=0; i < sortingArr.length; i++) {
    var found = false;
    for(var j=0; j < itemsArray.length && !found; j++) {
        if(itemsArray[j][1] == sortingArr[i]) {
            sortedArray.push(itemsArray[j]);
            itemsArray.splice(j,1);
            found = true;
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s7b2P/

Resulting order: Bob,Jason,Henry,Thomas,Anne,Andrew

Answer (score 6):

For getting a new ordered array, you could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and collect all items with the wanted key in an array and map the wanted ordered keys by taking sifted element of the wanted group.

```js
var itemsArray = [['Anne', 'a'], ['Bob', 'b'], ['Henry', 'b'], ['Andrew', 'd'], ['Jason', 'c'], ['Thomas', 'b']],
    sortingArr = [ 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'd' ],
    map = itemsArray.reduce((m, a) => m.set(a[1], (m.get(a[1]) || []).concat([a])), new Map),
    result = sortingArr.map(k => (map.get(k) || []).shift());

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's my fav, I do the same yet use `{}` instead of `Map` ‍♂️

Comment: @Nina Scholz I just scrolled through to find your answer and wasn't disappointed. I knew you would be here. Kudos to you for always helping out :)

Answer (score 6):

I hope that I am helping someone, but if you are trying to sort an array of objects by another array on the first array's key, for example, you want to sort this array of objects:

```
const foo = [
  {name: 'currency-question', key: 'value'},
  {name: 'phone-question', key: 'value'},
  {name: 'date-question', key: 'value'},
  {name: 'text-question', key: 'value'}
];
```

by this array:

```
const bar = ['text-question', 'phone-question', 'currency-question', 'date-question'];
```

you can do so by:

```
foo.sort((a, b) => bar.indexOf(a.name) - bar.indexOf(b.name));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let a = ['A', 'B', 'C' ]

let b = [3, 2, 1]

let c = [1.0, 5.0, 2.0]

// these array can be sorted by sorting order of b

const zip = rows => rows[0].map((_, c) => rows.map(row => row[c]))

const sortBy = (a, b, c) => {
  const zippedArray = zip([a, b, c])
  const sortedZipped = zippedArray.sort((x, y) => x[1] - y[1])

  return zip(sortedZipped)
}

sortBy(a, b, c)
```

Comment: Please consider adding a brief explanation/description explaining why/how this code answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I was looking for and I did for sorting an Array of Arrays based on another Array:

> It's On^3 and might not be the best practice(ES6)

```js
function sortArray(arr, arr1){
      return arr.map(item => {
        let a = [];
        for(let i=0; i< arr1.length; i++){
          for (const el of item) {
            if(el == arr1[i]){
              a.push(el);
            }   
            }
          }
          return a;
      });
    }
    
    const arr1 = ['fname', 'city', 'name'];
  const arr = [['fname', 'city', 'name'],
  ['fname', 'city', 'name', 'name', 'city','fname']];
  console.log(sortArray(arr,arr1));
```

It might help someone

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
let sortedOrder = [ 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b' ]
let itemsArray = [ 
    ['Anne', 'a'],
    ['Bob', 'b'],
    ['Henry', 'b'],
    ['Andrew', 'd'],
    ['Jason', 'c'],
    ['Thomas', 'b']
]
a.itemsArray(function (a, b) {
    let A = a[1]
    let B = b[1]

    if(A != undefined)
        A = A.toLowerCase()

    if(B != undefined)
        B = B.toLowerCase()

    let indA = sortedOrder.indexOf(A)
    let indB = sortedOrder.indexOf(B)

    if (indA == -1 )
        indA = sortedOrder.length-1
    if( indB == -1)
        indB = sortedOrder.length-1

    if (indA < indB ) {
        return -1;
    } else if (indA > indB) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
})
```

This solution will append the objects at the end if the sorting key is not present in the reference array.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this for a JSON payload I receive from an API, but it wasn't in the order I wanted it.

Array to be the reference array, the one you want the second array sorted by:

```
var columns = [
    {last_name: "last_name"},
    {first_name: "first_name"},
    {book_description: "book_description"},
    {book_id: "book_id"},
    {book_number: "book_number"},
    {due_date: "due_date"},
    {loaned_out: "loaned_out"}
];
```

I did these as objects because these will have other properties eventually.

Created array:

```
 var referenceArray= [];
 for (var key in columns) {
     for (var j in columns[key]){
         referenceArray.push(j);
     }
  }
```

Used this with result set from database.  I don't know how efficient it is but with the few number of columns I used, it worked fine.

```
result.forEach((element, index, array) => {                            
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < referenceArray.length - 1; i++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = element[referenceArray[i]];
        tr.appendChild(td);

    }
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this method.

```
const sortListByRanking = (rankingList, listToSort) => {
  let result = []

  for (let id of rankingList) {
    for (let item of listToSort) {
      if (item && item[1] === id) {
        result.push(item)
      }
    }
  }

  return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  const result = sortingArr.map((i) => {
    const pos = itemsArray.findIndex(j => j[1] === i);
    const item = itemsArray[pos];
    itemsArray.splice(pos, 1);
    return item;
  });
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66032502/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

This approach features a sorting algorithm where for each item of the order array, the data is searched for a corresponding item and this item is swapped by the left neighbor until the item is at the right position.

```
 a   b   b   d   c   b   data
<b>  a   b   d   c   b   right order of <>
 b  <c>  a   b   d   b
 b   c  <b>  a   d   b
 b   c   b  <b>  a   d
 b   c   b   b  <a>  d
 b   c   b   b   a  <d>
```

```js
const
    data = [['Anne', 'a'], ['Bob', 'b'], ['Henry', 'b'], ['Andrew', 'd'], ['Jason', 'c'], ['Thomas', 'b']],
    order = ['b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'd'];

let i = 0;

for (const o of order) {
    let j = i;
    while (data[j][1] !== o) j++;
    while (i !== j) {
        [data[j], data[j - 1]] = [data[j - 1], data[j]];
        j--;
    }
    i++;
}

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var i,search, itemsArraySorted = [];
while(sortingArr.length) {
    search = sortingArr.shift();
    for(i = 0; i<itemsArray.length; i++) {
        if(itemsArray[i][1] == search) {
            itemsArraySorted.push(itemsArray[i]);
            break;
        }
    } 
}

itemsArray = itemsArraySorted;
```

Answer (score 0):

With a numerical sortingArr:

```
itemsArray.sort(function(a, b){  
  return sortingArr[itemsArray.indexOf(a)] - sortingArr[itemsArray.indexOf(b)];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
var outputArray=['10','6','8','10','4','6','2','10','4','0','2','10','0'];
var template=['0','2','4','6','8','10'];
var temp=[];

for(i=0;i<template.length;i++) {
  for(x=0;x<outputArray.length;x++){
    if(template[i] == outputArray[x]) temp.push(outputArray[x])
  };
}

outputArray = temp;
alert(outputArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is immediate to achieve by a `Classifier`.

Just add all your items to a `Classifier` by converting each pair `[name, char]` to a tern `[char, name, char]`.

```
const 
    classifier = new Classifier()
        .letAll(data.map(([name, char]) => [char, name, char]));
```

This way, all the pairs `[name, char]` sharing same `char` are grouped in the same subtree within the `Classifier` internal tree structure.

```
const 
    got = sorting
        .map(char => classifier.view(true, char).poll());
```

The call `view(true, char)` provides a `Classifier.View` of the subtree addressed by the given `char`. This view is a `queue` of arrays expressed relative to the subtree. The first parameter `true` determines the order inside the `queue`. By passing `false` the items would appear in reverse order. The method `poll()` can therefore consume all the pairs `[name, char]` sharing the same `char`.

You can check validity of the proposed solution by:

```
import { Classifier } from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/Classifier.js";
import assert from "assert";

const 
    data = [
        ['Anne', 'a'],
        ['Bob', 'b'],
        ['Henry', 'b'],
        ['Andrew', 'd'],
        ['Jason', 'c'],
        ['Thomas', 'b']
    ],

    sorting = [ 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'd' ],

    expected = [
        ['Bob', 'b'], 
        ['Jason', 'c'], 
        ['Henry', 'b'],  
        ['Thomas', 'b'], 
        ['Anne', 'a'], 
        ['Andrew', 'd']
    ];

assert.deepEqual(got, expected)
```

It's important to notice that the `View` does not replicate the `Classifier` tree structure. It only offers an interface to deal with relative arrays. Any extraction of a pair `[name, char]` from the `View` results in the extraction of the corresponding tern `[char, name, char]` from the `Classifier` itself.

To become acquainted with the concepts of `Classifier` and `Classifier.View` you might want to explore the [@ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier/) library.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let itemsArray = [
    ['Anne', 'a'],
    ['Bob', 'b'],
    ['Henry', 'b'],
    ['Andrew', 'd'],
    ['Jason', 'c'],
    ['Thomas', 'b']
]

let sortingArr = [ 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'd' ]


function sortArray(sortedArr, unsortedArr, unsortedArrToSort){

    let holderArr = []
    let invertedIndex = {}
    // initialize
    unsortedArr.forEach((e)=>invertedIndex[e] = {indices:[],index:0})
    // create inverted index to save time
    unsortedArr.forEach((e,i)=>invertedIndex[e]['indices'].push(i))

    for(let sortValue of sortedArr){

        let currIndex = invertedIndex?.[sortValue]?.['index']

        let searchedIndex = invertedIndex?.[sortValue]?.['indices']?.[currIndex]

        if(searchedIndex===undefined)
        continue

        holderArr.push(unsortedArrToSort[searchedIndex])

        invertedIndex[sortValue]['index']+=1
    }

    return holderArr

}

console.log(sortArray(sortingArr, itemsArray.map(e=>e[1]), itemsArray))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the $.inArray() method from jQuery. You then could do something like this

```
var sortingArr = [ 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];
var newSortedArray = new Array();

for(var i=sortingArr.length; i--;) {
 var foundIn = $.inArray(sortingArr[i], itemsArray);
 newSortedArray.push(itemsArray[foundIn]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use intersection of two arrays.

Ex:

```
var sortArray = ['a', 'b', 'c',  'd', 'e'];

var arrayToBeSort = ['z', 's', 'b',  'e', 'a'];

_.intersection(sortArray, arrayToBeSort)
```

=> ['a', 'b', 'e']

if 'z and 's' are out of range of first array,  append it at the end of result

Answer (score -1):

```
this.arrToBeSorted =  this.arrToBeSorted.sort(function(a, b){  
  return uppthis.sorrtingByArray.findIndex(x => x.Id == a.ByPramaeterSorted) - uppthis.sorrtingByArray.findIndex(x => x.Id == b.ByPramaeterSorted);
});
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64981108/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score -5):

You can do something like this:

```
function getSorted(itemsArray, sortingArr) {
  var result = [];
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    result[i] = arr[sortArr[i]];
  }
  return result;
}
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/B96S7/1/).

*Note:* this assumes the arrays you pass in are equal in size. You'd need to add some additional checks if this may not be the case.

Refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046967/javascript-sort-an-array-based-on-another-array-of-integers/4046990#4046990).

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427141/quickest-way-to-sort-a-js-array-based-on-another-arrays-values/5427223#5427223)

Comment: This badly needs editing. not only does the jfiddle return the wrong result, the function argument names don't match the inner content?