# Sort an array of objects based on another array of ids

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have 2 arrays

```
a = [2,3,1,4]
b = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}]
```

How do I get `b` sorted based on `a`? My desired output would be

```
c = [{id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 1}, {id: 4}]
```

I would prefer to use Ramda or regular JS.

Comment: Do real `b` objects contain anything else than just `id`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - sort array based on another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/index.html) really shines for these types of problems.

Where the size of the data is small, we can use a simple [reduce](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#reduce) function, and [indexOf](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#indexOf) helper.

```
// match id of object to required index and insert
var sortInsert = function (acc, cur) {
  var toIdx = R.indexOf(cur.id, a);
  acc[toIdx] = cur;
  return acc;
};

// point-free sort function created
var sort = R.reduce(sortInsert, []);

// execute it now, or later as required
sort(b);
// [ { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 4 } ]
```

This works well for small(ish) data sets but the [indexOf](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#indexOf) operation on every iteration through the reduction is inefficient for large data sets.

We can remedy this by tackling the problem from the other side, lets use [groupBy](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy) to group our objects by their id, thus creating a dictionary lookup (much better!). We can then simply [map](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) over the required indexes and transform them to their corresponding object at that position.

And here is the solution using this approach:

```
var groupById = R.groupBy(R.prop('id'), b);

var sort = R.map(function (id) {
    return groupById[id][0];
});

sort(a);
// [ { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 4 } ]
```

Finally, this is yet another solution, which is very succinct:

```
R.sortBy(R.pipe(R.prop('id'), R.indexOf(R.__, a)))(b);
// [ { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 4 } ]
```

I love the way you can compose functions with behaviour and separate the algorithm from the data upon which it acts using [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/index.html). You end up with very readable, and easy to maintain code.

Comment: Could you make `sortInsert` a pure function? :)

Answer (score 42):

You can provide a custom comparison function to JavaScript's [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Syntax) method.

Use the custom comparison function to ensure the sort order:

```
var sortOrder = [2,3,1,4],
    items     = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];

items.sort(function (a, b) {
  return sortOrder.indexOf(a.id) - sortOrder.indexOf(b.id);
});
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description):

> - If compareFunction(a, b) returns less than 0, sort a to an index lower than b (i.e. a comes first).
> - If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behavior, thus, not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If compareFunction(a, b) returns greater than 0, sort b to an index lower than a (i.e. b comes first).

Since 2023 you can use [`toSorted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted) to generate a new, sorted array, without changing the original `items` array:

```js
const c = items.toSorted((a, b) => {
  return sortOrder.indexOf(a.id) - sortOrder.indexOf(b.id)
});
```

---

Hitmands made a very fair comment on the above solution:

> This approach is O(n2), and would cause performance issues in big sized lists. Better to build the dictionary first, so that it stays O(n)

The above solution might be slow for large inputs because it uses `indexOf` for every single comparison, and `indexOf` is already itself slow (O(n)) compared to dictionary lookups (O(1)).

To implement Hitmands' suggestion:

```
let sortOrder = [2,3,1,4],
    items     = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];

const itemPositions = {};
for (const [index, id] of sortOrder.entries()) {
  itemPositions[id] = index;
}

items.sort((a, b) => itemPositions[a.id] - itemPositions[b.id]);
```

Answer (score 15):

Using ES6 map and find

```
const a = [2,3,1,4];
const b = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];

// map over a, find it in b and return    
const c = a.map((i) => b.find((j) => j.id === i));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just create `c` based off of `a` without ever using `b`:

```
var a = [2,3,1,4];
var c = [];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){

    c.append({id:a[i]);

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: May not exactly be what the question has asked for but still a helpful perspective to think outside of the box

Answer (score 2):

Pretty good solution. Just keeping here for future use :)

```
const sortBy = (array, values, key = 'id') => ((map) => values.reduce((a,i) => 
a.push(map[i]) && a,[]))(array.reduce((a,i) => (a[i[key]] = i) && a, {}));
```

Usage

```
a = [2,3,1,4]
b = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}]

sortBy(b, a) // [{id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 1}, {id:` 4}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a helper object `c` for the indices.

```
{
    "1": 2,
    "2": 0,
    "3": 1,
    "4": 3
}
```

```js
var a = [2, 3, 1, 4],
    b = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }],
    c = a.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        r[a] = i;
        return r;
    }, {});

b.sort(function (x, y) {
    return c[x.id] - c[y.id];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(b, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

For greater objects, I suggest to use [Sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map).

Answer (score 1):

Or may be simpler

```
b.sort(function(obj1,obj2){
   return a.indexOf(obj1.id) > a.indexOf(obj2.id)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Ramda, you have to map objects in *b* to their index via the *mapObjIndexed* function and then search the value in *a*. You can try it  [here](http://goo.gl/CZxyiX).

```
var a = [2,3,1,4];
var b =  [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}]
R.find( R.propEq('id', a[0]), b )
R.values(R.mapObjIndexed(  (num, key, obj) => R.find( R.propEq('id', a[key]), b ) , b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use methods of the [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) object:

```js
var a = [2, 3, 1, 4];
var b = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];
var c = [];

a.forEach(el => c.push(b.find(e => e.id == el)));

console.log(JSON.stringify(c, 0, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative construction using Ramda that might be a bit more succinct, and the functions are pretty easy to repurpose for other things.

```js
const {indexBy, prop, map, flip} = R
const a = [2,3,1,4]
const b = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}]

const toIndexById = indexBy(prop('id'))
const findIndexIn = flip(prop)

const c = map(findIndexIn(toIndexById(b)), a)
console.log(c)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to iterate on [arcseldon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35559392/4099454)'s solution.

The right approach here is to flip the problem, instead of
*"sorting `a` based on the order given by `b`"*,
I'd rather *"enrich `b` with data coming from `a`"*

This lets you maintain the time complexity of this function down to `O(n)`,
instead of bringing it up to `O(n2)`.

```js
const pickById = R.pipe(
  R.indexBy(R.prop('id')),
  R.flip(R.prop),
);

const enrich = R.useWith(R.map, [pickById, R.identity]);


// =====

const data = [2, 3, 1, 4];
const source = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }];

console.log(
  enrich(source, data),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply You could use [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
    var a = [2, 3, 1, 4];
    var c = a.reduce((res,item)=>([...res,{'id':item}]),[])
    console.log(c)
```