# Sort array of objects by key name

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, ecmascript-6

I need to sort the keys to an exact order, for example I have the next array:

```
const arr = [
             {
               active: true,
               code: "1234",
               indentifier: "OPC-999",
               name: "Example",
               start: "02-12-1997",
             }
             {
               active: false,
               code: "4567",
               indentifier: "OPC-111",
               name: "Example",
               start: "03-02-2010",
             }
]
```

The exact order for every object should be: name, indentifier, code, start, active.

I don't need to sort by value but by key name.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need them to be in a specific order?

Comment: The component I'm trying to use needs me to put them in order

Comment: I don't think objects have a sense of order.

Comment: Can you share the component's code, then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)

Comment: No, I can't share the component code and @HereticMonkey no because that would be sorting by alphabetical order. Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: So, how do you want the items to be sorted? I am starting to think you will need a list rather than an array.

Comment: Then [Javascript sort an object by keys based on another Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35971456/215552) since apparently copy-paste-ability is key...

Comment: Why not hold a separate list of keys with the order? Alternatively, you could rebuild it as a list & failsafe the properties that are not included. But honestly, that would be flat out overkill: https://jsfiddle.net/mbfkn5g2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = {
    name: arr[i].name,
    indentifier: arr[i].indentifier,
    code: arr[i].code,
    start: arr[i].start,
    active: arr[i].active,
  }
}
```

After doing this, your `arr` will be sorted as you wanted:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Example",
    "indentifier": "OPC-999",
    "code": "1234",
    "start": "02-12-1997",
    "active": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Example",
    "indentifier": "OPC-111",
    "code": "4567",
    "start": "03-02-2010",
    "active": false
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `keys` array with the object keys in your desired order. Then you can `map` each object in the array, generating a new object with properties created in the order defined in the keys array:

```js
const arr = [
             {
               active: true,
               code: "1234",
               indentifier: "OPC-999",
               name: "Example",
               start: "02-12-1997",
             },
             {
               active: false,
               code: "4567",
               indentifier: "OPC-111",
               name: "Example",
               start: "03-02-2010",
             }
]

const keys = ['name', 'indentifier', 'code', 'start', 'active'];

const result = arr.map(o => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, o[k]])));

console.log(result);
```