# What should I do to sort an object by name ascending and descending

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have tried to find a solution and could find something that is close but not there yet. [Javascript sort an object by keys based on another Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971456/javascript-sort-an-object-by-keys-based-on-another-array)
I want to sort them by ABC ascending and descending and I don't know where to start.

```
const Accounts = {
  'thing': {
    password: '123',
  }
}

const sortedKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Accounts).sort();
//This returns the names but not the passwords
```

Comment: Stop using an object if you want to sort anything. An object is not an ordered collection. Use an array instead, e.g. `Object.entries(Accounts).map(([name, obj]) => ({name, ...obj}))`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to sort an Object? Are you sure you're not storing passwords in plain sight?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You can't sort a `Map` either

Comment: @Bergi `const sortedAsc = new Map([...someMap].sort());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then it's essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values).

From the linked question's comments:
"The ordering of object properties is non-standard in ECMAScript", so you can't do what you want to do directly.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
const Accounts = {
  'thing': {
    password: '123',
  }
} 

//get array keys and sort them
let sorted_keys = Object.keys(Accounts).sort();

//if you need your values too then use keys to access
sorted_keys.forEach(function(key) {//access each key and map to its value
    let value = Accounts[key]
    //do whatever with value
}
```

Comment: @ChillingCone426 Sure, use `sorted_keys.reverse();` to reverse the order of the ascending array. BTW, Stack Overflow recommends thoroughly researching a problem before posting to avoid a sea low-quality/low-effort questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
const sortedKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Accounts).sort();
```

The above `sortedKeys` will contain an array of sorted keys as you have seen. You can then map the sorted keys to their values and have a sorted object.

The code is a simpler version of what I just explained:

```js
const Accounts = {
  thing: { password: "123 }
}

const sortedAccounts = Object.keys(Accounts)
  .sort()
  .reduce((accumulator, key) => {
    accumulator[key] = obj[key];

    return accumulator;
  }, {});
```