# Sort selection of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript

I am trying to sort an array of objects that looks like so -

```
const originalArray = [
 { name: 'Blue', id: '123', category: 'none' },
 { name: 'Red', id: '145', category: 'none' },
 { name: 'Pink', id: '589', category: 'none' },
 { name: 'Orange', id: '267', category: 'none' },
 { name: 'Green', id: '781', category: 'none' },
]
```

I have another array which is my 'sort order' -

```
const sortList = [ 'Green', 'Pink', 'Blue' ]
```

The sort order I have does not include all of the items in the original array. I am trying to do this -

```
const sortedArray = originalArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return sortList.indexOf(a.name) - sortList.indexOf(b.name);
});
```

However when I console.log the sortedArray, it is exactly the same as the original array. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Ideally, I would like the array to be sorted and the ones not included in the sortList should just be at the end. Like so -

```
const sortedArray = [
 { name: 'Green', id: '781', category: 'none' },
 { name: 'Pink', id: '589', category: 'none' },
 { name: 'Blue', id: '123', category: 'none' },
 { name: 'Red', id: '145', category: 'none' },
 { name: 'Orange', id: '267', category: 'none' },
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort an array of objects based on another array of ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538509/sort-an-array-of-objects-based-on-another-array-of-ids)

Comment: Check if the name is not in the sort list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const originalArray = [
    { name: 'Blue', id: '123', category: 'none' },
    { name: 'Red', id: '145', category: 'none' },
    { name: 'Pink', id: '589', category: 'none' },
    { name: 'Orange', id: '267', category: 'none' },
    { name: 'Green', id: '781', category: 'none' },
];
const sortList = ['Green', 'Pink', 'Blue'];

// Separate the items in originalArray into two arrays
const inSortList = [];
const notInSortList = [];

originalArray.forEach(item => {
    if (sortList.includes(item.name)) {
        inSortList.push(item);
    } else {
        notInSortList.push(item);
    }
});

inSortList.sort((a, b) => sortList.indexOf(a.name) - sortList.indexOf(b.name));
const sortedArray1 = [...inSortList, ...notInSortList];
console.log(sortedArray1);
```

The above code first separates the items into two arrays, `inSortList` and `notInSortList`. Then, it sorts `inSortList` based on the order defined in `sortList` and finally concatenates the two arrays to get the desired sorted result.

Answer (score 3):

Your original code worked, but it put the unknown values first (red and orange).
I modified your code a bit and it now works:

```js
const originalArray = [
  { name: 'Blue', id: '123', category: 'none' },
  { name: 'Red', id: '145', category: 'none' },
  { name: 'Pink', id: '589', category: 'none' },
  { name: 'Orange', id: '267', category: 'none' },
  { name: 'Green', id: '781', category: 'none' },
];

const sortList = ['Green', 'Pink', 'Blue'];

const sortedArray = originalArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  const aIndex = sortList.indexOf(a.name);
  const bIndex = sortList.indexOf(b.name);

  if (aIndex === bIndex) return 0;
  else if (aIndex === -1) return 1;
  else if (bIndex === -1) return -1;

  return aIndex - bIndex;
});

sortedArray.forEach((value) => {
  console.log(value.name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If an item is not found `-1` is returned, you have to handle that case

```js
const originalArray = [
 { name: 'Blue', id: '123', category: 'none' },
 { name: 'Red', id: '145', category: 'none' },
 { name: 'Pink', id: '589', category: 'none' },
 { name: 'Orange', id: '267', category: 'none' },
 { name: 'Green', id: '781', category: 'none' },
]

const sortList = [ 'Green', 'Pink', 'Blue' ]


const sortedArray = originalArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  const aIndex = sortList.indexOf(a.name)
  if (aIndex < 0) return 1
  const bIndex = sortList.indexOf(b.name)
  if (bIndex < 0) return -1
  return aIndex - bIndex
});

console.log(sortedArray)
```