# Sort object array based on another array of keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays containing objects. One contains keys in some order and another has data and I need to sort the data array in order against the given sorted key array. How can I do this?

```js
var a = ['d','a','b','c'] ;
var b =  [{a:1},{c:3},{d:4},{b:2}];
```

The result should be:

```
result = [{d:4},{a:1},{b:2},{c:3]
```

Comment: Just FYI; nothing about this has to do with JSON - I have edited as such.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - sort array based on another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```js
var a = ['d','a','b','c'] ;
var b =  [{a:1},{c:3},{d:4},{b:2}];

b.sort(function(x,y){
  var xkey = a.indexOf(Object.keys(x)[0]);
  var ykey = a.indexOf(Object.keys(y)[0]);
  return xkey - ykey;
})

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(b,0,4);
```

Answer (score 5):

A different approach from above ones would be, using `Lodash` Javascript Library.

```js
var a = ['d','a','b','c'] ;
var b =  [{a:1},{c:3},{d:4},{b:2}];

var results = _.map(a,function(av) {
   var obj = {};
   obj[av] = _.find(b, av)[av];
   return obj
});

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.11.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach respects the keys in the objects of the array for sorting.

Only the items of `a` are used for lookup and their respective order.

> In this case `d` gets all sort value of the item of `b`, so `d` looks like
>
> ```
> [ 1, 3, 0, 2 ]
> ```
>
> While sorting with indices, we need `e`, which has simply the indices of `b`
>
> ```
> [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
> ```
>
> after sorting it became
>
> ```
> [ 2, 0, 3, 1 ]
> ```
>
> the wanted sort order. Now the original array is remapped to the new order.

But why?

Usually objects contains more than one property. If you use `Object.keys` and take just the first element, then you could go wrong, because this element is not the wanted element for getting the sort order.

To make it save, you need a different approach, which does not use `Array#indexOf` in combination with a fixed item of `Object.keys`.

```js
var a = ['d', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
    b = [{ a: 1 }, { c: 3 }, { d: 4 }, { b: 2 }],
    d = b.map(function (bb) {
        var k = -1;
        a.some(function (aa, i) {
            if (aa in bb) {
                k = i;
                return true;
            }
        });
        return k;
    }),
    e = b.map(function (_, i) { return i; });

e.sort(function (a, b) {
    return d[a] - d[b];
});

b = e.map(function (a) {
    return b[a];
});

document.write('<pre> ' + JSON.stringify(b, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force approach is to loop through each of a array and check the b array for it's presence.

```js
var a = ['d','a','b','c'] ;
var b =  [{a:1},{c:3},{d:4},{b:2}];

var ans = [];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
{
 for(var j = 0; j < b.length; ++j)
 {
   if(b[j][a[i]])
     ans.push(b[j]);
 }
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(ans, 0, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
result = a.map(function(key) {
    for(var i=0; i<b.length; ++i) {
        if(key in b[i]) return b[i];
    }
});
```