# How to sort 2nd array by sorting the 1st one using Javascript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have 2 array. I want to sort only first array and the second array should be shorted on the base of first array.

Before sorting:

```
arrTexts = ["Company", "Department", "Account"];
arrValue = ["nameCompany", "department", "account"];
```

Should be like this after shorting:

```
arrTexts = ["Account", "Company", "Department"];
arrValue = ["account", "nameCompany", "department"];
```

I know sorting by `arrTexts.sort();` But it is not so useful in above case.

Please not array length can be 300+. So, performance(sorting speed) also maters.

Can anybody please suggest me?

Comment: please add valid javascript arrays. what do you mean by *shorten*?

Comment: Why the 2nd array can't be sorted liked the first?.. Can you give a better example for that? And do what Nina said please. use [ ] instead of { }

Comment: How would your sorting method *know* what is the name, description, account of the company if all elements are just strings?

Comment: It's not an array. It's an object. A valid array should be enclosed within `[]` E.g. `var arr = ['a', 'b']`

Comment: Why `nameCompany` is before `deparment` and after `account`? No logic.

Comment: @SandrinaPereira If I will sort second array, it will be like `{"account", "department", "nameCompany"};` I want it sort according to index of first array.

Comment: Create a single array of objects rather than two separate arrays.  Also, search SO, this exact question has already been asked

Comment: @Justinas It should follow the index of first array. Please suggest

Comment: @NinaScholz I have edited. Please suggest if I am still wrong.

Comment: I think this answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code to get started.

```js
var arrTexts = [
  "Company", "Department", "Account"
];

var arrValue = [
  "nameCompany", "department", "account"
];

var sortedArr1 = arrTexts.sort();

var sortedArr2 = [];

sortedArr1.forEach(function(v, i) {
  var t = arrValue.find(function(_v) {
    return _v.toLowerCase().indexOf(v.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  });
  sortedArr2.push(t);
});

console.log(sortedArr1);
console.log(sortedArr2);
```

Comment: I have tried all solution. The quickest in all solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it :

```
arrTexts = ["Company", "Department", "Account"];
arrValues = ["nameCompany", "department", "account"];


arrTextsValues = {};
arrTexts.forEach(function(item, key){
    arrTextsValues[item] = arrValues[key];
})

arrTextsSorted = arrTexts.sort();
arrValuesSorted = [];

arrTextsSorted.forEach(function(item){
    arrValuesSorted.push(arrTextsValues[item]);
})

console.log(arrTextsSorted, arrValuesSorted);
```

It outputs this :

```
[ 'Account', 'Company', 'Department' ] 
[ 'account', 'nameCompany', 'department' ]
```

First I create an object that will hold a correspondance between texts and values, then I sort the texts and finally, I loop over the sorted texts to create an array holding the values in the correct order based of the correspondance object created earlier.

Hope this helps.

I don't know if it will suits your needs regarding performance issues. That's yours to find out :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the indices as a temporary array and sort it with the values of `arrTexts`. Then map the result to `arrValue`.

```js
var arrTexts = ["Company", "Department", "Account"],
    arrValue = ["nameCompany", "department", "account"],
    indices = arrTexts.map(function (_, i) { return i; }),
    values,
    texts;

indices.sort(function (a, b) { return arrTexts[a].localeCompare(arrTexts[b]); });
texts = indices.map(function (i) { return arrTexts[i]; });
values = indices.map(function (i) { return arrValue[i]; });

console.log(values);
console.log(texts);
```

Comment: This solution might not work if order of 2nd array is same as 1st array!!

Comment: @Pugazh, why not? i am sorting `indices` only, not the original array, and then build a new array based on the indices.

Answer (score 1):

```js
   var arrTexts = ["Company", "Department", "Account"];
   var arrValue = ["nameCompany", "department", "account"];
    
    
    // temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
    var mapped = arrTexts.map(function(el, i) {
      return { index: i, value: el };
    })
    
    // sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
    mapped.sort(function(a, b) {
      return +(a.value > b.value) || +(a.value === b.value) - 1;
    });
    
    // container for the resulting order
    var result = mapped.map(function(el){
      return arrValue[el.index];
    });
    console.log(result);
```