# Get object keys with the highest value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

Imagine an object like this:

```
var values = {
    "2": 1,
    "53": 2,
    "56": 4,
    "57": 9,
    "61": 2,
    "62": 16,
    "63": 2,
    "398": 24,
    ...
}
```

My goal is, to find the 10 object keys, which have the highest value. In this case: 398, then 62 and so on (= `[398, 62, ...]`). I know how I can put this into an array, don't know how to receive the property key though.

Important: I can't change the format because it's a server response.

I tried with a `for (key in values) {}` loop but have no idea how to move on.
[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array) and it's answer couldn't really help me either.

Comment: Create array of keys and then sort descending based on value and get first 10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As commented before:

- Create an array of keys: `Object.keys(object)`
- Sort this array based on value: `sort((a,b)=> object[b] - object[a])`
- Get necessary values: `keys.slice(0,n)`

```js
var value = {2:1,53:2,56:4,57:9,61:2,62:16,63:2,398:24};

function getKeysWithHighestValue(o, n){
  var keys = Object.keys(o);
  keys.sort(function(a,b){
    return o[b] - o[a];
  })
  console.log(keys);
  return keys.slice(0,n);
}

console.log(getKeysWithHighestValue(value, 4))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could sort by the values property and slice the result.

```js
var values = { 2: 1, 53: 2, 56: 4, 57: 9, 61: 2, 62: 16, 63: 2, 398: 24 },
    result = Object
        .keys(values)
        .sort(function (a, b) { return values[b] - values[a]; })
        .slice(0, 10)
        .map(Number);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` to get key values

```
var value = {
"2": 1,
"53": 2,
"56": 4,
"57": 9,
"61": 2,
"62": 16,
"63": 2,
"398": 24,
}
var parsedKeys = Object.keys(value).map(x => parseInt(x));
var sortedKeys = parsedKeys.sort(function (a, b) {  return b - a;  });
```

Now you can get highest top 10 keys by `sortedKeys.slice(0, 10);`

Comment: What if I have array of words with count ? ex:- `[ { "text":"hello", "size":10},{ "text":"world", "size":2} ,....]` same to 100 object and find top 10 text and store it in an array ?

Comment: See the example given [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy)

Answer (score -1):

```js
var value = {
    "2": 1,
    "53": 2,
    "56": 4,
    "57": 9,
    "61": 2,
    "62": 16,
    "63": 2,
    "398": 24
};

var sortable = [];
for (var key in value) {
    sortable.push([key, value[key]]);
}

sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
});

var result = [];
sortable.forEach(function(a) {
  result.push(a[0]);
});

console.log(result.slice(0, 10));
```