# get the name of the key that has the highest property value in nested javascript objects,

Tags: javascript

```
var food = {
"fruit":{"brand":{"grgrdgdr":true,"ggyugy":true}, "sold":2},
"vegetable" :{"brand":{"htrhtr":true},"sold": 1},
"snack":{"brand":{"htrhr":true},"sold": 3},
"other":{"brand":{"gdhshd":true},"sold":1},
....
...
...

};
```

How do I console log the object name that sold the most, 
in this case should be the word snack.

I find this link, but its structure is not similar to mine.
[Get object keys with the highest value in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717358/get-object-keys-with-the-highest-value-in-javascript)

any help is appreciated 
thanks in advance

Comment: what if more then one have the same top value?

Comment: if they have they same top value, choose anyone of key name that has those top same value

Comment: Dupe code to change is `.sort(function(a, b) {
    return food[b].sold - food[a].sold;
  })[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort by the values property and get the first item.

```js
var food = { fruit: { brand: { grgrdgdr: true, ggyugy: true }, sold: 2 }, vegetable: { brand: { htrhtr: true }, sold: 1 }, snack: { brand: { htrhr: true }, sold: 3 }, other: { brand: { gdhshd: true }, sold: 1 } };
    result = Object
        .keys(food)
        .sort((a, b) => food[b].sold - food[a].sold)
        [0];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yeah, like the link he posted.

Answer (score 1):

Find the max value first, and then filter the object to get objects having max `sold` value

```
var food = {
"fruit":{"brand":{"grgrdgdr":true,"ggyugy":true}, "sold":2},
"vegetable" :{"brand":{"htrhtr":true},"sold": 1},
"snack":{"brand":{"htrhr":true},"sold": 3},
"other":{"brand":{"gdhshd":true},"sold":1}}

var maxSold = Math.max(...Object.values(food).map(o=> o.sold))

var result = Object.keys(food).filter(o => food[o].sold ===maxSold)
console.log(result) //this will given all objects with max sold value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable & iterate the array twice. In the first iteration get the highest `sold`. Then on second iteration add the products whose `sold` value is same as the highest `sold`

```js
var food = {
  "fruit": {
    "brand": {
      "grgrdgdr": true,
      "ggyugy": true
    },
    "sold": 5
  },
  "vegetable": {
    "brand": {
      "htrhtr": true
    },
    "sold": 1
  },
  "snack": {
    "brand": {
      "htrhr": true
    },
    "sold": 3
  },
  "other": {
    "brand": {
      "gdhshd": true
    },
    "sold": 1
  },
  "someOtherfruit": {
    "brand": {
      "grgrdgdr": true,
      "ggyugy": true
    },
    "sold": 5
  }
}

let highestSold = 0;
let newObj = [];

for (let keys in food) {
  if (food[keys].sold > highestSold) {
    highestSold = food[keys].sold
  }
}

for (let keys in food) {
  if (food[keys].sold === highestSold) {
    newObj.push(food[keys])
  }
}

console.log(newObj[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your posted link [Get object keys with the highest value in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717358/get-object-keys-with-the-highest-value-in-javascript)

was quite close

```js
var food = {
"fruit":{"brand":{"grgrdgdr":true,"ggyugy":true}, "sold":2},
"vegetable" :{"brand":{"htrhtr":true},"sold": 1},
"snack":{"brand":{"htrhr":true},"sold": 3},
"other":{"brand":{"gdhshd":true},"sold":1}
  },
  result = Object
  .keys(food)
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return food[b].sold - food[a].sold;
  })[0] // or  .slice(0, 1); 

console.log(result,food[result]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var food = {
"fruit":{"brand":{"grgrdgdr":true,"ggyugy":true}, "sold":2},
"vegetable" :{"brand":{"htrhtr":true},"sold": 1},
"snack":{"brand":{"htrhr":true},"sold": 3},
"other":{"brand":{"gdhshd":true},"sold":1},
};


function getMostExpensivesKey(array) {
  let key = Object.keys(array)[0];

  Object.keys(array).forEach(function(k) {
    if(array[k].sold > array[key].sold) {
      key = k;
    }
  });

  return key;
}


console.log(getMostExpensivesKey(food));
```

Comment: note that this function will return the first key, if you want the last one change to >=