# How to order array by another array IDs (lodash / javascript)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to my second array to be ordered by the attribute `id` as in the first array.

**Here are my arrays**

First array

```
data : 
  items:
    0: {id: 14, attributes: Array(1)}
    1: {id: 8, attributes: Array(1)}
    2: {id: 4, attributes: Array(1)}
    3: {id: 1, attributes: Array(2)}
    4: {id: 2045, attributes: Array(2)}
```

Second array

```
data : 
  items:
    0: {id: 1, name: "test Product 1"}
    1: {id: 4, name: "test Product 1"}
    2: {id: 8, name: "test Product 1"}
    3: {id: 14, name: "test Product 1"}
    4: {id: 2045, name: "test Product 1"}
```

I tried it like this:

[Javascript - sort array based on another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array/27309301)

But I can't seem to get it working.
I know this was asked a lot but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: `data.items.sort( (a,b) => a.id - b.id );`

Comment: Is the second array already sorted by id?

Comment: Yes it is, but i want it to be ordered like it is in first array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

lodash

```
sorted = _.sortBy(items1, x => _.findIndex(items2, y => x.id === y.id))
```

If your arrays are fairly long, it might be more efficient to build an index first, and then sort by that:

```
index = _.fromPairs(_.map(items2, (x, i) => [x.id, i]));
sorted = _.sortBy(items1, x => index[x.id])
```

Comment: I was thinking of something like this, but couldn't figure it out. They might be, thanks for showing me also the efficient way

Answer (score 3):

You could sort by the indices of the first array.

```
items2.sort((a, b) =>
    items1.findIndex(({ id }) => a.id === id) -
    items1.findIndex(({ id }) => b.id === id));
```

```js
var items1 = [{ id: 14, attributes: [1] }, { id: 8, attributes: [1] }, { id: 4, attributes: [1] }, { id: 1, attributes: [1] }, { id: 2045, attributes: [1, 2] }],
    items2 = [{ id: 1, name: "test Product 1" }, { id: 4, name: "test Product 1" }, { id: 8, name: "test Product 1" }, { id: 14, name: "test Product 1" }, { id: 2045, name: "test Product 1" }];

items2.sort((a, b) => items1.findIndex(({ id }) => a.id === id) - items1.findIndex(({ id }) => b.id === id));

console.log(items2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Since i was already using lodash, i accepted answer of georg. But thank you for this answer really helpful to see it without lodash