# sort array of objects according list sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

Hello guys I have a task on sort. Here is the deal:
I have an array

```
arr = [{role:'mom', name:'a'}, {role:'dad', name:'d'}, {role:'bro', name: 'c'}]
```

and sort sequence list `sortSequence = ['dad','mom','bro']`
so according this list I need an output array to be equal

```
arr = [{role:'dad', name:'d'}, {role:'mom', name:'a'}, {role:'bro', name: 'c'}]
```

How can use `sort` method to do this?

```
const sortAccordingList = (list, arr) => {
    //... ?
}
```

Comment: Sort expects you to return a number. So if you take the difference between the index of the first elements role inside the sortSequence and the index of the second elements role, you know if first comes before second or not.

Comment: `let s = sortSequence.reduce((p, c, i) => (p[c] = i, p), {}); arr.sort(({role: a}, {role: b}) => s[a] - s[b]);`

Comment: I think this was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array)

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I searched, but didn't find it, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` to get the index of the role

```js
var sortSequence = ['dad', 'mom', 'bro'];
var arr = [{role:'mom', name:'a'}, {role:'dad', name:'d'}, {role:'bro', name: 'c'}];

arr.sort((a, b) => sortSequence.indexOf(a.role) - sortSequence.indexOf(b.role));

console.log(arr);
```

---

You can also make `sortSequence` as an object. This will make it easier to get the sort sequence. Like:

```js
var sortSequence = {dad:1,mom:2,bro:3};
var arr = [{role:'mom', name:'a'}, {role:'dad', name:'d'}, {role:'bro', name: 'c'}];

arr.sort((a, b) => sortSequence[a.role] - sortSequence[b.role]);

console.log(arr);
```