# Sort array of objects by another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have an array of objects that looks like this.

```
var items = [
  {id: 1150, title: 'im tyler'},
  {id: 1195, title: 'im josh'}
];
```

And another array that looks like this:

```
var sortArray = [
'1195',
'1150'
];
```

What i am trying to accomplish is a sorting based on result from the sort array. So in this scenario that items array should sort the object with id = 1195 as first in the list. Also if there is only one id in  the sortArray it should only display that object in the items array.

Wanted result:

```
var Newitems = [
  {id: 1195, title: 'im josh'}
  {id: 1150, title: 'im tyler'},
];
```

Comment: Summary answer: put items into an object with `id` as the key, then iterate through `sortArray` and look each one up.

Comment: Is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array You find the right answer there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over the sort array, and in each iteration find the element in the source array. If found, push the result to a new array.

Though it generates a new array, please note that the items still refer to the original array. The new array just contains the references to original items.

```js
var sortArray = [
  '1195',
  '1150'
];

var items = [
  {id: 1150, title: 'im tyler'},
  {id: 1195, title: 'im josh'}
];

var res = [];

sortArray.forEach(item => {
  res.push(items.find(i => i.id.toString() === item));
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object from sort array and then use that object to sort.

```js
var items = [{id: 1150, title: 'im tyler'},{id: 1195, title: 'im josh'}];
var sortArray = ['1195','1150'].reduce((r, e, i) => Object.assign(r, {[e]: i}), {})
items.sort((a, b) => sortArray[a.id] - sortArray[b.id]);
console.log(items)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, you need to filter the array of objects and then sort the objects by the order of `sortArray` (btw, it would be easier if the data has the same type).

```js
var items = [{ id: 1150, title: 'im tyler' }, { id: 1195, title: 'im josh' }],
    sortArray = ['1195', '1150'].map(Number),
    result = items
        .filter(({ id }) => sortArray.includes(id))
        .sort((a, b) => sortArray.indexOf(a.id) - sortArray.indexOf(b.id));
        
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.sort and array.indexOf

```js
var items = [
  {id: '1150', title: 'im tyler'},
  {id: '1195', title: 'im josh'}
];

var sortArray = [
'1195',
'1150'
];

items.sort((a, b) => sortArray.indexOf(a.id) - sortArray.indexOf(b.id));

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using map and filter, like this:

```js
var ordered = sortArray.map(id => {
    return items.filter(item => {
        return id == item.id
    });
});
```