# Why is this sort not worj

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I want to sort an array of objects and looks like this:

```
  [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "businessEntityId": "BE001",
            "financials": {
                "Npbt": 2323,
                "Interest": 123213,
                "Depreciation": 213123,
                "Ebit": 1312321,
                "EbitDa": 123123,
                "Leasing": 123213
            },
            "type": "Actual",
            "startDate": "2018-06-15T00:00:00.000Z",
            "endDate": "2018-06-15T00:00:00.000Z",
            "model": "Commercial",
            "duration": 12,
            "quality": "Unqualified"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "businessEntityId": "BE002",
            "financials": {
                "Npbt": 2323,
                "Interest": 123213,
                "Depreciation": 213123,
                "Ebit": 1312321,
                "EbitDa": 123123,
                "Leasing": 123213
            },
            "type": "Actual",
            "startDate": "2017-06-15T00:00:00.000Z",
            "endDate": "2017-06-15T00:00:00.000Z",
            "model": "Agribusiness",
            "duration": 12,
            "quality": "Audited"
        },


    ]
```

I know how do a basic sort for like sort by date but the requirements are a bit tougher. These are the sortingrules in desc. order of priority:

Modeltype:
1.Commercial
2.Agribusiness

If modeltype is Commercial the rules are:
1.Type : Actual and order of quality:Unqualified,Qualified,Unaudited.
2.Type: Projected and order of quality:Projection, Audited.

If modeltype is Aggribusiness the rules are:
1.Type : Historical and order of quality:Unqualified,Qualified,Unaudited.
2.Type: Actual and order of quality:Projection, Audited.

Like I said no straighforward sort but can anyone help me to get on the right path / how would I begin to solve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array

Comment: Would you have these in the same array? How would Commercial/Aggribusiness be sorted compared to one another - e.g., Commercial -> Aggribusiness or perhaps they'd be mixed in the list?

Comment: @AZ_ that question is if you have some other array that defines your order but the question doesn't have that.

Comment: order of quality:Unqualified,Qualified,Unaudited.... what does this mean, surely you will have to create an array to follow the order. @VLAZ

Comment: @bier hier Please show input and output with some more items in array. Here with this data we can't test if our solution is working or not.

Comment: @Vlaz It is the same array Commercial come before the Agribusiness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically, you could use an object for sorting and take `type` and `quality` for sorting.

```
var order = {
        model: { Commercial: 1, Agribusiness: 2 },
        Historical: { Projection: 1, Audited: 2 },
        Actual: { Unqualified: 1, Qualified: 2, Unaudite: 3 },
        BOTTOM: Infinity
    };

array.sort((a, b) =>
    order.model[a.model] - order.model[b.model] ||
    order[a.type][a.quality] - order[b.type][b.quality]
);
```

For unknow values, you could add a default value (dpending on the position, like `-Infinity` for a top, or `Infinity` for a bottom sorting) and use this pattern, like

```
(order.model[a.model] || order.BOTTOM) - (order.model[b.model] || order.BOTTOM)
```

For taking this approach, you need to skip a falsy (`0`) value in the `order` object.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) accepts a compare function. You can add your sort logic inside the compare function.

```
const data = []; // Put data here

const sortedData = data.sort((data1,data2)=>{
  // This function should return 1 if data1 > data2,
  // -1 if data2 > data1
  // And 0 if data1 === data2

  if(data1.model==="Commercial"){
    // Code for commercial
  }else{
    // Code for others
  }
})
```

Comment: if you will return  -> Return 1 if data1 > data2, <- here in your code how the if-else will be called?

Comment: I mean that the function as a whole should return these values, not necessarily at that portion

Comment: @AZ_ what he means is that the function should return the appropriate values, not use the `return` keyword at the point of the comment. Of course you use the return keyword inside your if/else

Comment: @AZ_ I have edited the answer to make it clearer. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: What about sorting in predefined quality order?