# How to sort a list on Google-Actions/Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I would like to know how you can sort the OptionItems in the list of Google DialogFlow. It seems that they are automatically sorted by the key of their OptionItem. I just want them displayed on the list in the order I push them in the list, so no auto-sorting would be best.

I got following code how I create an OptionItem:

```
const optionItems:{[key: string]: OptionItem} = {}

optionItems[outlet.outlet_id] = {
    synonyms: [
        outlet.outlet_id,
    ],
    title: outletOptionItemTitleText,
    description: outletOptionItemDescriptionText,
    image: {
        url: outletOptionItemImageUrlText,
        accessibilityText: outletOptionItemImageAccessibilityTextText,
    },
}
```

The optionItems are passed as parameter to the List Object of Google DialogFlow like below:

```
conv.close(showAvailabilityText,new List({
    items: optionItems,
}))
```

Can I pass another parameter to influence the order of the list? Or anything else?

Comment: What about sorting it when you receive the request? You can choose whatever sorting method you want.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array

Comment: This is how I try it at the moment. I also changed the sorting order to reverse, but Google DialogFlow sort the items automatically everytime according to their ID.