# Sorting using two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

There are two arrays:
The first one contain numbers, and the second one contains "weight" of the first array values.

It works like this:

```
arr1 = [56,65,100,89,180,90];
```

"Weight" of the numbers are calculated in this way:

```
 56 = 5+6 = 11;
 65 = 6+5 = 11;
 100 = 1+0+0 = 1; and so on..
```

So, `arr2 = [11,11,1,17,9,9];`

My question is how can I sort the values of the `arr1` according to values of `arr2`?

I tried to modify simple bubble sort for this problem, but nothing changed.

```js
function bubble(arr1, arr2) {
  var len = arr1.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++) {
      if (arr2[j] > arr2[j + 1]) {
        var temp = arr1[j];
        arr1[j] = arr1[j + 1];
        arr1[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr1;
}

arr1 = [56, 65, 100, 89, 180, 90];

arr2 = [11, 11, 1, 17, 9, 9];

console.log(bubble(arr1, arr2));
```

I expect the output of the bubble function to be `[100,180,90,56,65,89]`. 
This is why:

```
FirstArray -          [56,65,100,89,180,90] - arr1
"Weight of the values"[11,11, 1, 17, 9, 9 ] - arr2
Output                [100,180,90,56,65,89]
                      [1,  9,  9 ,11,11,17]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - sort array based on another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array)

Comment: You have to sort *both arrays*, not just one. Otherwise the arrays start to missmatch and you get chaos

Comment: @JonasWilms if second array is derived from first ,  then sorting arr1 alone works -  https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/WNeoaEv?editors=1010

Comment: Why not just supply a comparison function and compute the "weight" during the sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just calculate the weight on the fly while sorting:

```js
const arr = [56,65,100,89,180,90];

arr.sort( (a,b) => 
  (a + '').split( '' ).reduce( (sum,x) => sum + +x, 0 ) -
  (b + '').split( '' ).reduce( (sum,x) => sum + +x, 0 )
);

console.log( arr );
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of sorrting arr1 with logic mentioned in question

1. Sort **arr1** bycomparing sum of digits
2. Convert number to string and split it to array
3. Use reduce sum all the digits and compare with the array elements

```js
var arr1 = [56, 65, 100, 89, 180, 90];
var arr2 = [11, 11, 1, 17, 9, 9];

console.log(
  arr1.sort(
    (a, b) =>
      a
        .toString()
        .split("")
        .reduce((acc, v) => parseInt(acc) + parseInt(v)) -
      b
        .toString()
        .split("")
        .reduce((acc, v) => parseInt(acc) + parseInt(v))
  )
);
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/WNeoaEv?editors=1010

Comment: My thanks! I just feel a little bit weak in arrow functions, so I need more practice.