# How to order an array accordingly to another array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an associative array, with a number used as key, something like this:

```
    let array1 = [
    [456, {
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2",
    }],
    [789, {
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2",
    }],
    [123, {
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2",
    }]
];
```

and then I have another simply array like this:

```
let array2 = [123, 456, 789];
```

is there a way to order array1 accordingly to array2?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show your attempt.

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.map`, call the function on array2 and return the appropriate values from array1

Comment: *"I have an associative array"* -- JavaScript does not provide associative arrays. It provides the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) built-in class but you don't use it. There isn't any associative array (or something with the same functionality) in the code you posted. Just two regular arrays (i.e. indexed with consecutive integral numbers, starting with `0`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - sort array based on another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `reduce` method on `array1` and then place elements in result by index of the current element number in `array2`.

```js
let array2 = [123, 456, 789];
let array1 = [[456,{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}],[789,{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}],[123,{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}]]

const result = array1.reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
  r[array2.indexOf(k)] = [k, v];
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array1.sort((a, b) => array2.indexOf(a[0]) - array2.indexOf(b[0]));
```

How about this?