# How to sort the data by grouping it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I am trying to sort out the array based on the specific order. The data itself will include fruits, prices, etc. I am struggling to make a sort() function to arrange the order.

```
fruit = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Pear"];
const data = storeData.filter(...);

// sort the data
data.sort((a, b) => (a.fruit > b.fruit ? 1 : -1));   // output: apple, banana, orange, pear
```

I expect the result to be **`banana, orange, pear, apple`** instead of `apple, banana, orange, pear` or `banana, orange, apple, pear`.  I am still learning more. Thank you!

By the way, I am using Reactjs or javascript-based platform.

Comment: Hey. welcome to SOF. could you please elaborate on your question? I couldn't understand what you really want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - sort array based on another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array)

Comment: @mahdi Thank you for a warm welcome. I am trying to find a way to sort the data by grouping by fruits: Banana > Orange > Pear > Apple. The data that's called by API was not sorted, so I want to make a sort() function to put the fruits in the same order based on another array. 

Before sort() - `Banana, Orange, Apple, Pear`
After sort() - `Banana, Orange, Pear, Apple`

Comment: @femaleProgrammer1964 `fruit.sort(function(a, b){  
  return defaultOrder.indexOf(a) - defaultOrder.indexOf(b);
});` check this.

Comment: @mahdi Your contribution is helpful. It is similar to Bhavik's answer, but you both are correct. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the one of the possible option:

Let say, you need to filter fruit without filtering anything, you can use the below:

```
fruit.sort((a,b) => defaultOrder.i(a) > defaultOrder.indexOf(b) ? 1 : (-1));
```

In case if you need to use filtered data, please change `fruit.sort` to `data.sort` like;

```
data.sort((a,b) => defaultOrder.indexOf(a) > defaultOrder.indexOf(b) ? 1 : (-1));
```

if you want to chain the methods, here's the way

```
fruit
.filter(a => a !== 'Banana')
.sort((a,b) => 
defaultOrder.indexOf(a) > defaultOrder.indexOf(b) ? 1 : (-1));
```

if you have an object array, you can go for the following:

```
fruit.sort((x,y) => defaultOrder.findIndex(a => a == x.fruit  ) > defaultOrder.findIndex(b => b == y.fruit) ? 1 : (-1));
```

hope this helps.

Bhavik

Comment: OMG, it works well! I am glad you help a woman to learn how to be a good programmer. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: You're welcome!, It's community and we learn by sharing things, fyi: I've added another option in the case if you have an object.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
fruit.sort( (itemA , itemB) => defaultOrder.indexOf(itemA) - defaultOrder.indexOf(itemB));
```