# TypeScript - Sort in-place with lodash syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting, lodash, mutators

Is there a function like the lodash [`_.orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy) that sorts a collection **in-place**? I know there is the builtin [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) but it receives a compare function, and I have some `ObjectIteratee`s (which is what lodash receives). Can I somehow turn the lodash input into an input that's appropriate for the builtin method?

Code example:

```
let arr = [{ k: 5, v: 3}, {k: 2, v: 7}]
orderBy(arr, 'k') // should order arr by k in-place.
orderBy(arr, val => val.v) // should order arr by v in-place.
```

Comment: Possible but you'd have to re-implement a lot of things. It's trivial to get a transformation function and apply it to both operands (Lodash's `iteratee`) but then you have to also account for reverse sorting or alphabetic sorting, etc. So it's *simple* if you only want ascending order of numbers but becomes complex fast for any other variation.

Comment: That's why I'm asking if it exists. I don't plan on implementing it myself since it's too complex and I better find a different approach (not sort in-place for example). But I wanted to check if maybe a solution already exists since it seems like a common problem.

Comment: People just use Lodash, usually. In general, generating a new array is cleaner but if you *really need* in-place reordering, then you could use `_.orderBy`, get a new array, then sort the initial array based on the resulting one. That would be more computationally and memory intensive but it doesn't necessarily have to matter. Depends on your data.

Comment: Also, I don't need support for descending order. But I do need support for the cases I showed in the question and also for a list of strings (`['k', 'v']`). Again, I don't want to implement it myself.

Comment: @VLAZ So like use the index in the result of `_.orderBy` for the comparison function of `.sort()`? That's an interesting idea. Not so elegant IMHO. But it does solve the problem...

Comment: Yes, since you have an array of objects, you can very safely compare them with `===` (or find them with `indexOf`, etc). An object is only equal to itself. So, you can then  [sort the initial array based on the one returned by `_.orderBy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array). I agree, it's not very elegant but it's a very cheap way to leverage the Lodash functionality for in-place sorting.

Comment: But it's really inefficient since for every pair I'll have to find both of its elements in the sorted list (so `O(n)` for each pair). Or I can use the sorted list to generate a mapping between an element and its index to make the comparison function more efficient. I don't like this solution, but thank's for the original idea!