# how to sort an array of arrays based on other array JS

Tags: javascript, sorting

array or arrays

```
var items = [
    ['alice','bob', 'emma', 'isabella'],
    ['emma','sofia', 'alice', 'bob'],
    ['bob','emma', 'alice']
];
```

how to map items in concrete order `['alice','emma','bob', ..other]`

every array can have items like `alice, bob and emma` and other

Comment: What do you mean by "*map items in concrete order*"? Are you asking to `.sort()` them?

Comment: items.map((item) => ( //here item i want to be in order alice, bob, emma, others

Comment: And how is that order chosen? Is it an alphabetical order, a random made-up one, the one of the first array in `items`?

Comment: you want sorted the item array for the first occurence in the inner-array or you want the name-arrays are sorted?

Comment: Add commas (`,`) after all-but-last inner arrays.
Then, use this: `items.map(item=>item.sort())`.

Comment: Javascript is not like Haskell or Prolog,  It will not try to match literals.

Comment: @ iAmOren sort will order alphabetically, but how to order by given list

Comment: so if the input is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, then defines `concrete` order is `[3, 2, 4, 5]`, then the output will be `[3, 2, 4, 5, 1]`?

Comment: @Bergi in case we speak only about an array, for e.g `['emma','sofia', 'alice', 'bob']` how to reorder it in `['alice','emma','bob','sofia']`, other e.g. `['bob','sofia', 'emma', 'alice']` reorder in `['alice','emma','bob','sofia']`

Comment: @Sphinx yes, like your example, but only with strings instead of numbers

Comment: Use sort() and subtract reference index a from reference index b. Assumes you have a preordained order for all items included in your arrays

Comment: @Alex So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13304543/1048572) is what you were looking for?

Comment: @Bergi yup, thx

Comment: the link @Bergi provided should give you some idea. but if the order of `other` elements is not matter, probably you will want to try this one: `function sort(src, concrete) {
  let orderDict = concrete.reduce((pre, cur, index) => {
    pre[cur] = index + 1
    return pre
  }, {})
  return src.map(items => {
    return items.sort((a, b) => {
      let t1 = orderDict[a] || 9999999
      let t2 = orderDict[b] || 9999999
      return t1 - t2
    })
  })
}`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var items = [
    ['alice','bob', 'emma', 'isabella'],
    ['emma','sofia', 'alice', 'bob'],
    ['bob','emma', 'alice']
];

const NAME =  ['alice','bob', 'emma'];
let res = [];

items.forEach(names => {
    names.sort((a,b) => {
        indA = NAME.indexOf(a);
        indB = NAME.indexOf(b);
        if (indA!=-1)
            return (indB!=-1) ? indA-indB : -1;
        else return (indB!=-1) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    res.push(names);
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: You should return `0` if both `indA` and `indB` are `-1`, otherwise this is not a consistent comparison function. Easiest done by `return (indA==-1) - (indB==-1) || indA - indB;`

Comment: @Bergi - You are right. Thanks, I corrected it.