# how to sort the object by keys array?

Tags: typescript, sorting

I have a keys array like ['D', 'B', 'A', 'C'] and object like below.

```
obj = [
    {key: 'C', value: 'CCC'},
    {key: 'B', value: 'BBB'},
    {key: 'D', value: 'DDD'},
    {key: 'A', value: 'AAA'}
]
```

What is the best way to sort that obj as the order of the keys like below, I prefer to use Lodash.

```
sorted_obj = [
    {key: 'D', value: 'DDD'},
    {key: 'B', value: 'BBB'},
    {key: 'A', value: 'AAA'},
    {key: 'C', value: 'CCC'}
]
```

I can think of the way to use additonal data structure like Map, but I really want to make this simple. Does anyone have a nice way to implement this? :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - sort array based on another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array)

Comment: unclear how that is even sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this quite easily without `lodash`.

The trick is to prepare a map of key to position in the sorted array (for the given input it is `{D: 0, B: 1, A: 2, C: 3}`). You can make use of `Array.sort()` function with a custom compare function then:

```js
const sorted = ['D', 'B', 'A', 'C'];
const obj = [
    {key: 'C', value: 'CCC'},
    {key: 'B', value: 'BBB'},
    {key: 'D', value: 'DDD'},
    {key: 'A', value: 'AAA'}
];

const sortedMap = sorted.reduce((acc, v, idx) => ({...acc, [v]: idx}), {});
const result = obj.sort((a, b) => sortedMap[a.key] - sortedMap[b.key]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can also use `obj.sort((a, b) => sorted.indexOf(a.key) - sorted.indexOf(b.key))` instead of creating a new object.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Which would increase time complexity to quadratic. It all depends on tradeoffs OP is willing to take.