# JS how to sort() one array based on another array’s sortation

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

When A is .sorted(), it becomes 6, 7, 8, so those number
get new index values, so do the same for B. get current index of the values inside B, then rearrange it based on A’s new arrangement.
So when A = 6,7,8, B would be u, z, h

```
var arrA = [8, 6, 7] // B follows this arr (A)
var arrB = ['h', 'u', 'z'] // B follows A

arrA.sort()
// output: 6, 7, 8

// arrB.followA’s arrangement somehow 
// output: u, z, h


arrA.reverse()
// output: 8, 7, 6

// arrB.follow A’s arrangement
// output: h, z, u


console.log(arrA);
console.log(arrB)
```

Comment: Does this question/answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a two-dimensional working array, whose elements are pairs of values from `arrA` and `arrB`:

```
var work = [];
arrA.forEach(function( v, i ) {
    work[ i ] = [ arrA[i], arrB[i] ];
});
```

Now you can arrange `work` in any order, and the values from `arrA` and `arrB` will stay in lockstep:

```
work.sort(function(x, y) {
    return Math.sign( x[0], y[0] );
});
```

(In the above example, we are ordering by the element in slot 0, which is from `arrA`. To order by the elements in `arrB`, change 0 to 1.)

Now you can alter `work`, e.g.:

```
work.reverse();
```

And extract the corresponding elements that were originally from `arrA`:

```
let newAarrA = work.map(function(x) {
    return x[0]; // from arrA
});
console.log(newArrA);
```

(Change 0 to 1 to get the corresponding elements from `arrB` instead.)

Comment: How would we go about doing it with three arrays?

Comment: @Ginfio Change `work[ i ] = [ arrA[i], arrB[i] ];` to `work[ i ] = [ arrA[i], arrB[i], arrC[i] ];` to add the elements from `arrC` to the `work` array. For every element `elmt` in `work`, you can find the corresponding element from `arrA`, `arrB`, or `arrC` in `elmt[0]`, `elmt[1]`, and `elmt[2]` accordingly. Change the sort algorithm to use any of them in your sort criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Use a brute force sort routine.  Swap elements in "ary", and if those swap, then swap the same indexes in "bry".  This way the index swapping will mirror each other.

```
var ary = [8, 7, 4, 3, 5, 1, 6];
var bry = ['u', 'z', 'y', 'a', 'b', 'f', 'r'];
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

for (i = 0; i < ary.length-1; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < ary.length-1; j++){
      if (ary[j] > ary[j+1]){
          let bigger = ary[j];
          ary[j] = ary[j+1];
          ary[j+1] = bigger;

     // make bry swap the same indexes as ary above
          bigger = bry[j];
          bry[j] = bry[j+1];
          bry[j+1] = bigger;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible if it is two different arrays. the simple approach to solve ur problem is to convert your second array into an object.

```
let b = {
    8: 'H',
    6: 'U',
    7: 'Z'
}

arrB = arrA.map((val) => return b[val]);
```

and use this object to get the value for array B based on the values of array A.

correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: What if it is 2 different arrays? Is there a way to push the second array into the first one so it becomes one like you have it above. I have two different arrays: arrA [8, 6, 7], and arrB [h, u, z], now pus arrB to arrA so it becomes an object like you have jt above b = {8:h, ...}

Comment: arrA.forEach((key, index) => b[key] = arrB[index]); will map the arrays into object like I have above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "Sorting with map" technique, you basically use a temporary array that maps `arrB`'s elements to values of `arrA` elements and then sort it.

```js
var arrA = [8, 6, 7] // B follows this arr (A)
var arrB = ['h', 'u', 'z'] // B follows A

var tmpMap = arrB.map((el, i) => ({ index: i, value: arrA[i] }));

tmpMap.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);

var arrB = tmpMap.map(el => arrB[el.index]);

console.log(arrB);
```