# How to sort JavaScript array items by same position in second array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have two types of arrays,

With the same number of items, in one are a plane array in the second I have their new indexes.

First array :

```
let arrayOfPersons = [
 {
    myName: "Person 0"
 },
 {
    myName: "Person 1"
 }
....
];
```

Indexes have defaulted from 0 to n.

A new array of the new indexes:

```
let newIndexOfPerson = [
    { 
      myName: "Person 0" // or just old index 0 from array above
      newPersonIndex: 1
    }
....
];
```

So,
How I can sort objects with their old indexes (from 0 to n) with new index in the `newIndexOfPerson` array?

Thank you!

Comment: Reformat the second array into `{"Person 0": 1}`, then it should be pretty simple to sort the first one with a simply custom `sort` callback…!?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array

Comment: I would not even consider this being a `sort` task, or is the OP somehow forced to mutate the array like it happens by/with `sort`?

Answer (score 0):

So, you'd like to sort array `newIndexOfPerson` by newPersonIndex?

You could use javascript method sort(), so you don't need to write complex functions by yourself. [check sort() method from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

the code you'd like to have would be something like this.

```
newIndexOfPerson.sort((a, b) => (a.newPersonIndex> b.newPersonIndex) ? 1 : -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

One side-effect of using `sort` on the **newIndexOfPerson** is that it performs sorting *in place*, rather than returning a new array with the entries sorted, so **newIndexOfPerson** array itself will be modified.

If this is unwanted, you may sort a copy of this array (use `newIndexOfPerson.slice()` to make one).

However, if you really need 2 arrays to read data from *and* you know the correct indecies to begin with, rather than trying `sort` with a custom sorter, it may be more elegant and faster to use `reduce` to create a new array and fill its entries according to the indecies and data specified in **newIndexOfPerson**:

```js
arrayOfPersons = newIndexOfPerson.reduce((newArrayOfPersons, entry) => {
        newArrayOfPersons[entry.newPersonIndex] = {
            myName: entry.myName
        };
        return newArrayOfPersons;
    }, 
    new Array(arrayOfPersons.length)
);
```

This code has linear time complexity, while `sort` has logarithmic complexity.

It can be easily modified work with "old indecies" in **newIndexOfPerson** instead of just plain data. This solution, of course, expects that the lengths of arrays match and all the indecies are set correctly (otherwise, you'll get gaps in the resulting array).