# How to solve a JS logic problem where some values have to increment based on a previous value keeping always a specific order

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a problem I have in my JS which is related to the following snippet

```
const signatureOrder = role => {
  let order;
  switch (role) {
    case 'GUARDIAN':
      order = 2;
      break;
    case 'ASSENTEE':
      order = 3;
      break;
    case 'COUNTERSIGNEE':
      order = 4;
      break;
    default:
      order = 1;
      break;
  }

  return order;
};
```

This method basically takes a role which currently is 4: CONSENTEE, GUARDIAN, ASSENTEE, COUNTERSIGNEE.

The CONSENTEE is always 1 and the order is always as the numbers from 1 to 5.

However, there can be a situation where I can have like multi roles coming:

```
1 consented 
2 guardians
2 assentee
1 countersignee
```

This will be translated by the method in the following order

```
1 consented
2 Guardian
2 Guardian
3 Assentee
3 Assentee 
4 Countersignee
```

This is not very correct and the output should be an increment of the single values but keeping the order fixed as below:

```
1 Consented
2 Guardian
3 Guardian
4 Assentee
5 Assentee
6 Countersignee
```

so what happens is that if we have already a guardian the next guardian becomes the previous guardian + 1 but stays always after Consentee and before Assentee.

The scenarios areas:

- consentee is the one always be there is always 1
- Always we have 4 roles
- but we can have different combinations like no guardians, no assentee, yes countersigned and so on
- The always present role is consentee the other roles are present or not depending of the situation
- We can have already a list of this roles and adding again guardian should change the values for example
  we have C 1, G 2, A 3 and we add G so will change +1 everywhere so will have
  c1, G 2, G 3, A 4 ...

I would like to understand how to solve this in the right manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you need something like this:

```
const sortRoles = rolesArray => {
    const orderOfRole = {
        'CONSENTED': 1,
        'GUARDIAN': 2,
        'ASSENTEE': 3,
        'COUNTERSIGNEE': 4
    }
    rolesArray.sort((role1, role2) => orderOfRole[role1] - orderOfRole[role2])
}
```

where, in the end, the order is just the index in the sorted array, incremented by 1:

```
roles = ['GUARDIAN', 'ASSENTEE', 'ASSENTEE', 'CONSENTED']
sortRoles(roles)
roles.map((role, index) => console.log(`${index + 1}: ${role}`))
// 1: CONSENTED
// 2: GUARDIAN
// 3: ASSENTEE
// 4: ASSENTEE
```

You can extend this to having an object for the role, instead of a string. In that case you just need to extract the string from the object in the comparison function of `sort()` and use it like above.

Comment: I saw this better as seems most near what I need.
I need help to adapt to what I need if you can help.
In my case, the array coming with the roles contains other data as you can see from this example https://pastebin.com/CKxmSQwP
Will, you able to fix or send me the script adjusted to what I need, please
if not clear I can explain

Comment: One thing maybe not clear the inputs from user comes single and are compared against the already roles present in the list. 
and then I save one input as signOrder = ... 
This means I have a guardian from input and check with the list and I see I have only CONSENTEE so the GUARDIAN is save with signOrder = 2
then if another GUARDIAN comes I see I have C and G 1 so that saved as G3
Hope this makes it clear as I'm not saving a bulk of data but a single input called signOrder for the specific role.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort all your elements based on an *orderArray*. Then, assign the order based on the element index.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44063445/3788470):

```js
const orderArray = ['CONSENTEE', 'GUARDIAN', 'ASSENTEE', 'COUNTERSIGNEE']

const elements = ['CONSENTEE', 'ASSENTEE', 'GUARDIAN', 'COUNTERSIGNEE', 'ASSENTEE',  'GUARDIAN']

elements.sort(function(a, b){  
  return orderArray.indexOf(a) - orderArray.indexOf(b);
});

const withOrder = elements.map((el, i) => { 
  return {role: el, order: i+1}
})
console.log(withOrder)
```