# Javascript - Sorting an array of objects based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays. They look like this but are longer in my code.

```
let arrayA = [{heading: "heading2", body: "text body2"}, {heading: "heading", body: "text body"}, {heading: "heading4", body: "text body4"}, {heading: "heading3", body: "text body3"}]
let arrayB = ["heading", "heading2", "heading 3", "heading 4"]
```

My html page needs to loop over arrayA and for each item return

```
<h1>item.heading</h1>
<p>item.body</p>
```

How would i go about sorting arrayA to get the same order as arrayB ?

Comment: Why is `arrayA` an array instead of an object like `{"heading2": "text body2", ...}`

Comment: You can find multiple previous questions about how to sort an array of objects, or to sort based on another array, note that in your specific case you don't need to use the second  array, having `arrayA.sort((a,b) => (a.heading > b.heading) ? 1 : -1 )`  is enough

Comment: ArrayA contains articles, and each article is made of a heading and a body.

Comment: Please note I do not want to sort them alphabetically, this might not be clear at first glance. They need to be sorted in the order of appearance of arrayB

Comment: in this case you can refer to the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44063445/2834925

and have `arrayA.sort((a, b) => arrayB.indexOf(a.heading) - arrayB.indexOf(b.heading));`

Comment: also note that the arrayB 3rd and 4th items are a bit different, there's a space before the number (3 & 4)