# how to sort an array in comparison to another array

Tags: javascript

```
let selected_variation = [{
    "type": "Capacity",
    "value": "512G",
  },
  {
    "type": "Color",
    "value": "#000000",
  }
]

let attributes = [{
    "id": "Color",
    "name": "Color",
    "type": "swatch",
    "items": [{
        "displayValue": "Green",
        "value": "#44FF03",
        "id": "Green"
      },
      {
        "displayValue": "Cyan",
        "value": "#03FFF7",
        "id": "Cyan"
      },
      {
        "displayValue": "Blue",
        "value": "#030BFF",
        "id": "Blue"
      },
      {
        "displayValue": "Black",
        "value": "#000000",
        "id": "Black"
      },
      {
        "displayValue": "White",
        "value": "#FFFFFF",
        "id": "White"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "Capacity",
    "name": "Capacity",
    "type": "text",
    "items": [{
        "displayValue": "512G",
        "value": "512G",
        "id": "512G"
      },
      {
        "displayValue": "1T",
        "value": "1T",
        "id": "1T"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

so I have these two arrays one I am creating to track the selected variation of the product from the user there is a bug in it the order of the variation in my created array depends on which order the user clicks on the input fields I need to map my array in the order of the resulted api and the variations are not fixed it actually varies according to the product so my expected output

#### Output

```js
let selected_variation = [
   {"type":"Color","value":"#000000"},
   {"type":"Capacity","value":"512G"}
]
```

the same order the API is following

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - sort array based on another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try this:

```html
const order = attributes.map((attribute) =>
  selected_variation.find((v) => v.type === attribute.id)
);

console.log(order)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Based on accepted answer of this question: [Javascript - sort array based on another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array)

```js
const selected_variation = [{
    "type": "Capacity",
    "value": "512G",
  },
  {
    "type": "Color",
    "value": "#000000",
  }
]

const attributes = [{
    "id": "Color",
    "name": "Color",
    "type": "swatch",
    "items": [{
        "displayValue": "Green",
        "value": "#44FF03",
        "id": "Green"
      },
      {
        "displayValue": "Cyan",
        "value": "#03FFF7",
        "id": "Cyan"
      },
      {
        "displayValue": "Blue",
        "value": "#030BFF",
        "id": "Blue"
      },
      {
        "displayValue": "Black",
        "value": "#000000",
        "id": "Black"
      },
      {
        "displayValue": "White",
        "value": "#FFFFFF",
        "id": "White"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "Capacity",
    "name": "Capacity",
    "type": "text",
    "items": [{
        "displayValue": "512G",
        "value": "512G",
        "id": "512G"
      },
      {
        "displayValue": "1T",
        "value": "1T",
        "id": "1T"
      }
    ]
  }
]

selected_variation.sort((a, b) => {  
  return attributes.findIndex(attr => attr.id === a.type) - attributes.findIndex(attr => attr.id === b.type);
});

console.log(selected_variation);
```

But it will work really long if there will be a lot of elements because we must to loop through `attributes` array twice for each pair again and again. But if we will use a little more memory we can greatly optimize the algorithm. The main idea is to create a dictionary where the keys are ids of attributes and values are they index in `attributes` array:

```js
const selected_variation = [{
    "type": "Capacity",
    "value": "512G",
  },
  {
    "type": "Color",
    "value": "#000000",
  }
]

const attributes = [{
    "id": "Color",
    "name": "Color",
    "type": "swatch",
    "items": [{
        "displayValue": "Green",
        "value": "#44FF03",
        "id": "Green"
      },
      {
        "displayValue": "Cyan",
        "value": "#03FFF7",
        "id": "Cyan"
      },
      {
        "displayValue": "Blue",
        "value": "#030BFF",
        "id": "Blue"
      },
      {
        "displayValue": "Black",
        "value": "#000000",
        "id": "Black"
      },
      {
        "displayValue": "White",
        "value": "#FFFFFF",
        "id": "White"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "Capacity",
    "name": "Capacity",
    "type": "text",
    "items": [{
        "displayValue": "512G",
        "value": "512G",
        "id": "512G"
      },
      {
        "displayValue": "1T",
        "value": "1T",
        "id": "1T"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const attributesMap = new Map();

attributes.forEach((attribute, index) => attributesMap.set(attribute.id, index))

selected_variation.sort((a, b) => attributesMap.get(a.type) - attributesMap.get(b.type));

console.log(selected_variation);
```