# Facing the issue with Sorting Array Object Inside the Array using angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, sorting

I am trying to perform the sorting array inside the object inside the array

**here my First Array Object :**

```
firstObj = [{
    id: "111",
    name: "one",
    type: "user"
},
{
    id: "222",
    name: "two",
    type: "user"
},
{
    id: "333",
    name: "three",
    type: "admin"
},
{
    id: "444",
    name: "four",
    type: "user"
},
{
    id: "555",
    name: "five",
    type: "user"
},
{
    id: "666",
    name: "six",
    type: "admin"
}
]
```

**here my Second Array Object :**

```
secondObj = [
    {
        ids: ['333', '666', '555', '222'],
        name: "handlers"
    }
]
```

I am successfully sorting First array using below line.

```
firstObj.sort((p1,p2) => (p1.id > p2.id) ? -1 : 1);
```

I need a Second array Object ids array Sort with comparing a firstObj id.

I tried many ways But had no luck. Can Anyone Suggest to me How It's possible?

**Expected Output:**

```
secondObj = [
    {
        ids: ['222', '333', '555', '666'],
        name: "handlers"
    }
]
```

Comment: *Second array Object ids array Sort with comparing a firstObj id.* You mean arrange the ids array based on the sequence from `firstObj`?

Comment: *"I am successfully sorting First array using below line"* No, that `sort` callback is incorrect. It should be returning `0`, not `1`, when the elements are equal. See MDN's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) or any example from a reputable source.

Comment: The array is `secondObj[0].ids`. That's what you sort.

Comment: @YongShun Yes You are correct.

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya look at the explanation in my answer

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am trying to do => SecondObj ids array Sort with comparing a firstObj id. I mean arrange the ids array based on the sequence from firstObj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let firstObj = [{
    id: "111",
    name: "one",
    type: "user"
},
{
    id: "333",
    name: "two",
    type: "user"
},
{
    id: "222",
    name: "three",
    type: "admin"
},
{
    id: "444",
    name: "four",
    type: "user"
},
{
    id: "555",
    name: "five",
    type: "user"
},
{
    id: "666",
    name: "six",
    type: "admin"
}
];

let secondObj = [
    {
        ids: ['333', '666', '555', '222'],
        name: "handlers"
    }
]

let sortingArr = firstObj.map(x => x.id);

secondObj[0].ids.sort((a, b) => {
   return sortingArr.indexOf(a) - sortingArr.indexOf(b);
});

console.log(secondObj[0].ids);
```

Note: If your first array is always sorted in ascending order, you can simply sort the second array in ascending order too.

Comment: I tried this is work. But, I am trying to arrange the secondObj ids array based on the sequence from firstObj

Comment: If the firstObj is sorted in ascending order - then you are just sorting the second in ascending order too

Comment: If the firstObj isn't always sorted in ascending order - refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array) thread

Comment: Yes, my firstObj is not always sorted in ascending order. I already watch this thread. This is done opposite to mine.

Comment: secondObj.ids.sort((a, b) => //here I don't know How to access the firstObj Id);

Comment: Okay, Gotcha Thank you So much I need a Map and Access it. previously, I am trying to access with directly firstObj like firstObj[a].id // But, It's return with undefined.