# how to do compare and sort from two array

Tags: javascript

How do we compare and sort based on 2nd array

```
const arr1 = [{
        name: 'jimmy',
        age: 33,
        sport: 'football'
    },
    {
        name: 'Sam',
        age: 35
    },
    {
        name: 'Ricky',
        age: 32,
        sport: 'hockey'
    },
    {
        name: 'johnson',
        age: 30
    },
];

const arr2 = [{
        name: 'jimmy',
        age: 33,
        item: 'not found'
    },
    {
        name: 'Sam',
        age: 38
    },
    {
        name: 'johnson',
        age: 30
    },
    {
        name: 'Ricky',
        age: 32
    },
];
```

So sorting should happen base on second array.

```
let arMerge = arr1.map((el1) => {

    let matchEl = arr2.find((el2) => el2.name == el1.name);

    if (matchEl) {
        new Map([...el1.entries()].sort());
        return {
            ...el1,
            ...matchEl
        };
    } else {
        return el1;
    }
});
```

expected

```
[{
    name: 'jimmy',
    age: 33,
    sport: 'football'
    item: 'not found'
}, {
    name: 'Sam',
    age: 35
}, {
    name: 'johnson',
    age: 30
}, {
    name: 'Ricky',
    age: 32,
    sport: 'hockey'
}],

console.log(arMerge)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a JavaScript array based on another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/sort-a-javascript-array-based-on-another-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
finalArray = arr2.map(function(obj) {
    return obj.value;
});

arMerge.sort((a, b) => finalArray.indexOf(a.value) - finalArray.indexOf(b.value));
```