# Sorting an array based on an array of IDs with different RANGE

Tags: javascript

I found and I knew how to sort an array based on another array of IDs but with the same range [like this topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/sort-a-javascript-array-based-on-another-array).

I have an array like this:

```
matches = [ 
            "league": {
            "id":6,
            "score": "score 1",
            },
            "league": {
            "id": 9,
            "score": "score 2",
            },
            "league": {
            "id": 12,
            "score": "score 3",
            },
            "league": {
            "id": 6,
            "score": "score 4",
            },
            "league": {
            "id": 12,
            "score": "score 5",
            },
            "league": {
            "id": 3,
            "score": "score 6",
            },
            "league": {
            "id": 83,
            "score": "score 7",
            },
            "league": {
            "id": 76,
            "score": "score 8",
            },
      ]
```

The issue that I have a a very big complex data (above an example of data), I tried to sort this example following a list of IDs like that `var ids =[6,12,3]`

I did something like this:

```
 result = [];

 matches.forEach(function (a) {
result[ids.indexOf(a.league.id)] = a;
});

console.log(result);
```

But that give only the sort of three first IDs `[6,12,3]` and ignore the other IDs.

it's possible to sort the array like this:

```
    matches = [ 
            "league": {
            "id":6,
            "score": "score 1",
            },
            "league": {
            "id": 6,
            "score": "score 4",
            },
            "league": {
            "id": 12,
            "score": "score 3",
            },
            "league": {
            "id": 12,
            "score": "score 5",
            },
            "league": {
            "id": 3,
            "score": "score 6",
            },
            "league": {
            "id": 9,
            "score": "score 2",
            },
            "league": {
            "id": 83,
            "score": "score 7",
            },
            "league": {
            "id": 76,
            "score": "score 8",
            },
      ]
```

The logic of sorting is to have ids cited in array of Ids first and then the rest of list of data with no changes?

Comment: Don't use the JSON tag or the term for JavaScript literals. Your array isn't valid JSON syntax.

Comment: What's the sorting logic?

Comment: _"I did something like this:"_ - `matches` is an array, so `matches(function (a) {...});` does not even make sense to begin with.

Comment: @jabaa is sorting the Ids first but following the array of Ids and then keep the rest of data with no changes

Comment: @jabaa you can see the second example of JSON data and you can remark that I have the Ids in array of Ids are first and the others Ids (not included) be not sorted and with no changes

Comment: @CBroe is just a mistake and I made edit in the topic!

Comment: Please explain in detail why the duplicate is not useful for you?

Comment: The code defining matches above is invalid and throws a syntax error.

Comment: @SalmanA I have a list of leagues and ids of important league in an array of Ids but some Ids in the list of sorted league are not included, so I sort the data with important league first but the others with Ids not included will be in the list but with no changes?

Comment: @Nll improvise. If its not found (indexOf returns -1) then change it to 9999. Rest is straight forward.

Comment: @James Maybe I did a mistake somewhere but I did not see it yet I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for order by the `id` array.

For unknown `id` take a large value, like `Infinity` to keep this items at the end of the array.

```js
const
    data = [{ league: { id: 6, score: "score 1" } }, { league: { id: 9, score: "score 2" } }, { league: { id: 12, score: "score 3" } }, { league: { id: 6, score: "score 4" } }, { league: { id: 12, score: "score 5" } }, { league: { id: 3, score: "score 6" } }, { league: { id: 83, score: "score 7" } }, { league: { id: 76, score: "score 8" } }],
    ids = [6, 12, 3],
    order = Object.fromEntries(ids.map((id, i) => [id, i + 1]));

data.sort((a, b) =>
    (order[a.league.id] || Infinity) - (order[b.league.id] || Infinity)
);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```